# Extracting a number from between parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression designed to extract a number from between two parenthesis. It had been working fine until we made the input string customizable. Now, if a number is found somewhere else in the string, the last number is taken. My expression is below:

```
int icorrespid = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(subject, @"(\d+)(?!.#\d)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);
```

If I send the string `This (12) is a test`, it works fine, extracting the 12. However, if I send `This (12) is a test2`, the result is 2. I realize I can change the RightToLeft to LeftToRight, which will fix this instance, but I only want to get the number between the parenthesis.

I am sure this will be easy for anyone with any regular expression experience (which is obviously not me). I am hoping you could show me how to correct this to get what I want, but also give a brief explanation of what I am doing wrong so I can hopefully improve.

Thank you.

**Additional Information**

I appreciate all of the responses. I have taken the agreed upon advice, and tried each of these formats:

```
int icorrespid = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(subject, @"(\(\d+\))(?!.#\d)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);

int icorrespid = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(subject, @"(\(\d+\))", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);

int icorrespid = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(subject, @"\(\d+\)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);
```

Unfortunately, with each, I get an exception stating that the input string was not in a correct format. I did not get that before. I'm sure that I could resolve this without using a regular expression in a minute or two, but my stubbornness has kicked in.

Thank you everyone for your comments.

Comment: You could capture the parenthesis by including escaped parenthesis in your capture and then parse them out; that would do the trick.

Comment: What about `12.1` or `-5`? Are you interested in them or just positive integers?

Comment: @DavidG: I'm only interested in positive integers, but you are correct; I should have specified that.

Comment: @Tim I've updated my answer to show where you went wrong.

Comment: Another solution using lookaround: `@"(?<=\()\d+(?=\))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
\(#(\d+)\)
```

The brackets are escaped `\(` and `\)` and inside them is the normal search for numbers.

If you use the `.Value` property, it will give you the number surrounded by brackets. Instead you need to use the `Groups` collection. So to use in your code, you do this: (now with added error checking!)

```
var match = Regex.Match("hgf", @"\(#(\d+)\)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
{
    var icorrespid = Convert.ToInt32(match);
}
else
{
    //No match found
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the statement you made, but still get the error about the input string not being in the correct format. I assume it is talking about the RegEx statement, and not the subject string.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted it too and it works. What is the content of `subject`?

Comment: If `subject` is empty, it will give you that error.

Comment: Subject is "(#124) - Test1"

Comment: So do we need to look for the `#` symbol too?

Comment: My mistake. Yes, that will always be there.

Comment: OK, fixed it to check for the `#`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your help. Hopefully I can remember this and improve. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape parenthesis in regex, because they mean something

```
@"(\(\d+\))(?!.#\d)
```

or, if you didn't actually intend your number to be caught in a group

```
@"\(\d+\)(?!.#\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
\(\d+\)(?!.#\d)
```

`(` and `)` are reserved characters known as a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses have a meaning in regex, so you need to escape them:

```
\(\d+\)
```

The actual meaning is to create a capture group, so if you're relying on a capture group in your code, you need another pair of parentheses like this:

```
\((\d+)\)
```

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of the `(?!.#\d)` part is from your question, but if you do need it, you can leave it where it is (just append it to the end of either of the versions above)